# Pymc3: Optimizing parameters with multiple data?

Tags: python, pymc3, bayesian-networks

I've designed a model using Pymc3, and I have some trouble optimizing it with multiple data.

The model is a bit similar to the coal-mining disaster (as in the Pymc3 tutorial for those who know it), except there are multiple switchpoints.

The output of the network is a serie of real numbers for instance:
`[151,152,150,20,19,18,0,0,0]`

```
with Model() as accrochage_model:


       time=np.linspace(0,n_cycles*data_length,n_cycles*data_length)

       poisson = [Normal('poisson_0',5,1), Normal('poisson_1',10,1)]

       variance=3

       t = [Normal('t_0',0.5,0.01), Normal('t_1',0.7,0.01)]

       taux = [Bernoulli('taux_{}'.format(i),t[i]) for i in range(n_peaks)]

       switchpoint = [Poisson('switchpoint_{}'.format(i),poisson[i])*taux[i] for i in range(n_peaks)]

       peak=[Normal('peak_0',150,2),Normal('peak_1',50,2),Normal('peak_2',0,2)]

       z_init=switch(switchpoint[0]>=time%n_cycles,0,peak[0])
       z_list=[switch(sum(switchpoint[j] for j in range(i))>=time%n_cycles,0,peak[i]-peak[i-1]) for i in range(1,n_peaks)]

       z=(sum(z_list[i] for i in range(len(z_list))))
       z+=z_init

       m =Normal('m', z, variance,observed=data)
```

I have multiple realisations of the true distribution and I'd like taking all of them into account while performing optimization of the parameters of the system.

Right now my "data" that appears in observed=data is just one list of results , such as:

```
[151,152,150,20,19,18,0,0,0]
```

What I would like to do is give not just one but several lists of results,
for instance:

```
data=([151,152,150,20,19,18,0,0,0],[145,152,150,21,17,19,1,0,0],[151,149,153,17,19,18,0,0,1])
```

I tried using the shape parameter and making data an array of results but none of it seemed to work.

Does anyone have an idea of how it's possible to do the inference so that the network is optimized for an entire dataset and not a single output?